# Conditionate percentage formula Crystal reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, percentage

What I'm trying to do is to get the percentage of quotes that got converted into sales orders by each sales reps. So I have something that looks like this

```
John Doe

Sales orders     Quotes

2302000        
2304921         90039393
2353647
2609439
2340055
```

Given that info, 20% of orders by the rep were converted from a quote. the logic obviously is (#qt/#so)*100, but I don't know how to type in that formula in SQL into the FORMULA FIELDS part. Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following formula to group's header or footer section:

```
// {@% Total}
IF Count({table.order_id},{table.rep})<>0 THEN
  Count({table.quote_id},{table.rep}) / Count({table.order_id},{table.rep}) * 100
```